# Mockito : Not able to mock interface

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java2

I have a public interface `Repository` and when I try to `@Mock` it using mockito it gives following error

```
            org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
            Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.my.package.repository.Repository.

            Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
            If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


            Java               : 1.8
            JVM vendor name    : JetBrains s.r.o
            JVM vendor version : 25.152-b01
            JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
            JVM version        : 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01
            JVM info           : mixed mode
            OS name            : Linux
            OS version         : 4.4.0-109-generic


            Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
```

Following is the full stack trace log

```
    Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:63)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 19 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/net/Uri
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.<init>(MethodList.java:90)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.getDeclaredMethods(TypeDescription.java:7232)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType.getDeclaredMethods(TypeDescription.java:3349)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.doAnalyze(MethodGraph.java:576)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.analyze(MethodGraph.java:537)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.doAnalyze(MethodGraph.java:573)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$Default.compile(MethodGraph.java:508)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodGraph$Compiler$AbstractBase.compile(MethodGraph.java:408)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default.prepare(MethodRegistry.java:418)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:162)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:155)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:2560)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:2662)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:94)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    ... 36 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.Uri
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 56 more
```

As told in the error message , `Repository` is a **non-private & non-final** interface. But still why it is giving this error?

My interface method returns `RxJava` observables. Does it make any problem for mockito?

Below given is the sample test code

```
public interface Repository {
     Maybe<Integer> getUserCount();
 }
```

Test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class LoginPresenterTest {
   @Mock
   Repository mRepository;
  @Test
  public void repoTest() {
    when(mRepository.getUserCount()).thenReturn(Maybe.just(1));

 }
}
```

these are the mockito and Junit versions

```
testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.20"
```

Im using Java 8

Below are my project dependencies

```
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"

implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'

implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"

implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:multidex:$rootProject.ext.multidexVersion"

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$rootProject.ext.picassoVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.ext.okHttpVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.ext.okHttpVersion"
implementation "com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:$rootProject.ext.okhttp3DownloaderVersion"

debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$rootProject.ext.leakCanaryVersion"
releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$rootProject.ext.leakCanaryVersion"
testCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$rootProject.ext.leakCanaryVersion"

implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.ext.butterKnifeVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.ext.butterKnifeVersion"


implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.ext.firebaseVersion"
implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.7'

implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.ext.rxJavaVersion"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.ext.rxAndroidVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.ext.retrofitRxJavaAdapterVersion"




    minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 27
compileSdkVersion = 27
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.2'

supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'
rxJavaVersion = '2.1.6'
rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'
junitVersion = '4.12'
mockitoVersion = '2.7.20'

picassoVersion = '2.5.2'
daggerVersion = '2.12'
retrofitVersion = '2.2.0'
retrofitRxJavaAdapterVersion = '2.3.0'
okHttpVersion = '3.6.0'
okhttp3DownloaderVersion = '1.1.0'
leakCanaryVersion = '1.5.4'
butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
multidexVersion = '1.0.1'
firebaseVersion = '10.2.6'
```

Comment: try to add some of your test code to make things clearer

Comment: added some portion of the code.

Comment: what artifact are you using? mockito-core? which version?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski   updated the question

Comment: is this the only interface that is problematic.. or its a general problem with mocking

Comment: Your code above doesn't show you calling `mock()` ...is that done elsewhere?

Comment: It seems like this is the only interface that is problematic. Because I created one more sample Interface   `public interface DummyInterface{
        int getCount();
    }`
 and its mocking properly

Comment: are you sure that rx library is visible during the testing phase?

Comment: `when(mDummyInterface.getCount()).thenReturn(1);` this is properly compiling

Comment: _are you sure that rx library is visible during the testing phase?_ how can I check that

Comment: @Jrd took your code and tried it out. Works fine. Can you publish your entire dependencies list so that we can see if anything is interfering with the mocking.

Comment: I have updated the question with full stack trace log. can u look into that?

Comment: @user1676688 u need rxjava dependencies or all dependencies?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: android/net/Uri` seems to be root cause of this particular problem

Comment: But why? does `Rx` Observable type internally use it so that mockito can't mock it?

Comment: @Jrd all dependencies please.

Comment: @user1676688 updated question

Comment: @Jrd There are a lot  of version properties that you have not put value for. We will not be able to reproduce the issue unless you give us complete details

Comment: @user1676688 Missed it. updated the same in question

Comment: @Jrd I am missing quite a few libraries like android compat when I try to set this up. I have added maven.google.com to list of repositories. Is there a pre-step or any particular repository I must have in my list?

Comment: `  google()` in repositories

Comment: @user1676688 any update?

Comment: @Jrd I am facing the problem with dependencies not being found for some reason. I will troubleshoot when I have time. I am travelling right now

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues and it turns out I was missing this package:
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-android/5.3.1

for Kotlin DSL app gradle
`androidTestImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-android:5.3.1")`

Separate issue but related:

Then for me the `{on} {doReturn}` from the [Docs](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) wasn't working.

and `when` needed to be escaped with back ticks like `` `when` `` so it's not using the builtin `when` from Kotlin language